# Source in Darash Moshe on own understanding

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, quotations, moshe-feinstein

It is [said](https://www.truetorahjews.org/qanda/regret) that in Darash Mose דרש משה Parashas Korach, the following quote can be found from Rabbi Moshe Feinstein zt'l

> Korach thought that every Jew is entitled to fulfill the laws of the
> Torah in accordance with his own understanding. Korach's logic told
> him that a tallis made of techeiles was exempt from tzitzis, that a
> house full of seforim was exempt from mezuzah, and that he was
> entitled to be a kohein. But this is a great error; one must keep the
> Torah only as explained by the poskim of his time, who possess the
> traditions and methods of learning passed down from one sage to
> another throughout the generations. Without this, one is bound to make
> mistakes, often in the most serious of transgressions. In our long
> history we have seen many groups of heretics and wicked men who have
> based their beliefs on some inference from the Torah or the words of
> Chazal. Only the scholars and sages of the generation are to be
> entrusted with interpreting the words of Hashem Yisborach.

I've looked, but could not find it. Does someone know where to find this quote?

Also, the quote says "who possess the traditions and methods of learning passed down from one sage to another throughout the generations"- Does this means that you cannot make your own interpretation, since you might make mistakes with the interpretation? What does Rav Moshe mean with this?

Comment: See also https://www.scribd.com/doc/13615801/Rav-Soloveitchik-The-Common-sense-Rebellion-Against-Torah-Authority

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the quote itself or what Rav Moshe himself was basing the quote on?

It is the (Hebrew)  Dorosh Moshe 15:3 or the third Davar Torah on Parshas Korach.

As far where Rav Moshe is based on. There are many sources that say such things but it looks  like Rav Moshe is making an abridgment of the Kuzari 3:35-41 with added references to groups other than the Karaites that the Kuzari is discussing.

Not sure what you mean by "create" your own way of learning, based on the methods used by other.

Comment: Thank You. Is it maybe possible to provide a link for me to the quote from Rav Moshe? I am having trouble finding it. What I meant with creating your own way of learning is that the quote says one must keep the Torah only as explained by the poskim of his time, who possess the traditions and methods of learning passed down from one sage to another throughout the generations."- Does this means that you cannot make your own interpretation, since you might make mistakes with the interpretation? What does Rav Moshe mean with this?

Comment: Darash Moshe isn't available online other than Otzar HaChochmah

Comment: I found it on Otzar HaChochmah, but a translation would be much appreciated of what Rav Moshe writes about this subject. My Hebrew is not that good yet.

Comment: Artscroll has a translation but it's obviously not online

Comment: @robev I have access to Otzar ha-Chochmah but am really confused about how the single volume on there corresponds to the two-volume Artscroll translation (both of whose volumes run from Bereishit to V'zot ha-B'rachah). I also can't find anything by reference to "the third d'var Torah on Parashat Korach". Can you offer any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly Rabbi Shalom Rosner recounts that Rav Soloveitchik [made](https://issuu.com/anglomedia/docs/torah_tidbits_issue_1375_korach_no_marks/s/10659703) a similar -if not the same- point on parshas Korach.

> Rav Soleveitchik referred to this phenomenon as the “common sense”
> rebellion against Torah authority. There are many people who have the
> attitude that logic dictates, and anything that lacks common sense
> should be discarded. This leads to a determination that certain
> mitzvot do not apply today since the rationale for the mitzva is no
> longer applicable. It flatters people’s common intelligence and
> empowers each individual to follow their own logical judgment. In the
> Rav’s words:
>
> These self-styled “poskim” concede their lack of formal training in
> Jewish texts and sources, but they insist nonetheless on their right
> to decide fundamental religious questions on the basis of “common
> sense”.
>
> The idea of Jews rebelling against authority and declaring, “I know
> better than the rabbi and the posek,” is not a new phenomenon. People
> justify their positions by stating: “I know this is what he spoke
> about in shul, but he is not up to-date. He doesn’t know all the
> facts.” The idea of someone using his own common sense to pasken is
> not new.

[Audio recording of the shiur quoted above](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/749191/rabbi-joseph-b-soloveitchik/the-rebellion-of-korach/)

Comment: Hi Yisroel K, thank you very much for this great answer and a very warm welcome to Mi Yodeya.